# Has many through update / with pivot laravel 5.5

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have several tables (all of them with created_at, updated_at, deleted_at) :

- sectors
- lang_sector
- valuechains
- lang_valuechain
- segments
- lang_segment
- keyneeds
- keyneed_lang

the tables are linked in this order : 
sectors has many valuechains
valuechains has many segments
segments has many keyneeds

Here is my model :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Sector extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "sectors";
    protected $fillable = ['admin_id'];
    protected $dates = [ 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at' ];

    public function langs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')
            ->withPivot('sectname', 'sectshortname', 'segname_slug',
                'sectdescription', 'sectshortdescription'
            )
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin');
    }

    public function valuechains()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Valuechain');
    }
    public function segments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Segment', 'App\Valuechain');
    }
    public function keyneeds()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Keyneed', 'App\Segment', 'App\Valuechain');
    } 
}
```

In my destroy controller :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $sector = Sector::findOrFail($id);

    $sector_ids = $sector->langs()->allRelatedIds();
    foreach ($sector_ids as $id){
        $sector->langs()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['lang_sector.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()]);
    }
    $sector->valuechains()->update( [ 'valuechains.deleted_at' => Carbon::now() ] );
    $sector->segments()->update( [ 'segments.deleted_at' => Carbon::now() ] );
    $sector->keyneeds()->update( [ 'keyneeds.deleted_at' => Carbon::now() ] );
    Sector::where('id', $id)->delete();

    return redirect()->route('sectors.index')->with('success', 'Sector deleted');
}
```

My issue is that it doesn't update the following tables : segments and keyneeds (which have created_at, updated_at and deleted_at fields) and their pivot tables too ... And that i have an error message :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Field: 'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: update `segments` inner join `valuechains` on `valuechains`.`id` = `segments`.`valuechain_id` set `segments`.`deleted_at` = 2018-05-10 06:54:54, `updated_at` = 2018-05-10 06:54:54 where `valuechains`.`sector_id` = 2)

it adds : `updated_at`

**I succesfully updated :**

- sectors table
- valuechains table
- lang_valuechain pivot

**My issue is to update**

- segments table by using : $sector->segments()
- keyneeds table by using : $sector->keyneeds()

And their pivot table as well... I read the documentation but it doesn't help. 
I use the update() method because $sector->segments()->delete() is trying to make a hard delete...

Comment: Why is it trying to make a hard delete? Did you implement soft deletions in the `Segment` model? Or generally all models you want to soft delete? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#deleting-models

Comment: I just forgot to put soft delete to all the models i use ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find an issue to this.. Not very elegant but it's working on the "main" tables. I'll have to solve the little problem on pivot tables :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $sector = Sector::findOrFail($id);
    $valuechains = Valuechain::where('sector_id','=',$sector->id)->get();
    foreach ($valuechains as $valuechain) {
        $segments = Segment::where('valuechain_id', '=', $valuechain->id )->get();
        $valuechain->langs()->updateExistingPivot($valuechain->id, ['lang_valuechain.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()]);

        foreach ($segments as $segment) {
            $keyneeds = Keyneed::where('segment_id', '=', $segment->id)->get();
            $segment->langs()->updateExistingPivot($segment->id, ['lang_segment.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()]);
            $segment->delete();

            foreach ($keyneeds as $keyneed) {
                $keyneed->langs()->updateExistingPivot($keyneed->id, ['keyneed_lang.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()]);
                $keyneed->delete();
            }
        }
        $valuechain->delete();
    }
    $sector->langs()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['lang_sector.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()]);
    $sector->delete();

    return redirect()->route('sectors.index')->with('success', 'Secteur suppprimé');
}
```